# OpenSSH 5.3 setting UMASK for SFTP chroot env, dosen't work at all

Tags: ssh, sftp, chroot

I tried to override umask setting on SFTP connection in chrooted env.
I couldnt use subsytem diffrente than internal-ftp.

In OpenSSH_5.3p1 (Debian-3ubuntu4, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009)
there's umask setting directly from command.

How do you able to set ?

My sshd config is:

```
Match User myuser
ChrootDirectory /mnt/jail/myuser/
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
#ForceCommand /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -l DEBUG3
#ForceCommand /bin/sh -c 'umask 002; /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server'
ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 002
```

anyway, it dosent works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want the patch solution, here is another workaround:

In sshd_config:

```
# Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp /usr/local/bin/sftpwrapper

# And the Match Group, ChrootDirectory, etc... declarations
```

And in /usr/local/bin/sftpwrapper (chmod 755, chown root:root)

```
#!/bin/bash --
umask 0002
exec /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Users in the chrooted group, can still has /bin/false as shell.

Comment: I've tried even this solution but sftp-server couldnt start from sshd
and when i tried to use Cyberduck sftp-server respond with "/bin/bash not found" dosen't accept any connection

Comment: You can change first line to something like "#!/usr/bin/env bash" or the right path to the bash interpreter on your server.

Comment: Sorry @poisonbit i catch this error when i try to login with an user without shell. It should say nothing, but ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch you might want to look at which adds a `SftpUmask` option to `sshd_config`.

http://sftpfilecontrol.sourceforge.net/

You can also use pam_umask per [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1107974#5).  In `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
session    optional     pam_umask.so umask=0002
```

Comment: I couldnt fix sshd daemon with sftpfilecontrol

BTW I've tried to insert pam_umask but seems dosent work

Comment: I was able to get it to work putting the pam_umask line at the top of /etc/pam.d/sshd and restarting.  I'm using /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server; I didn't try it with internal-sftp.